# Query for date value AFTER specified patindex value in TEXT column using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am querying for a date value that follows a specific phrase in the same text column value. There are a number of date values in this text column but I'm needing only the DATE following the phrase I've found via a patindex value.  Any help/direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    NotesSysID, 
    PATINDEX('%Demand Due Date:%', NoteText) AS [Index of DemandDueDate text], 
    PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', NoteText) AS [Index of DemandDueDate date], 
    SUBSTRING(NoteText, PATINDEX('%Demand Due Date:%', NoteText), (PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', NoteText)))
FROM 
    #temp_ExtractedNotes;
```

Here is a pic of my data, please note that the 2nd index is LESS than the Index of DemandDueDate text found and I'm needing the subsequent date AFTER the Index of DemandDueDate text column.  Hopefully this makes sense.

[image]

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for info.  I think that I would still have the same issue.  Any suggestions on my question?  Thanks.

Comment: A couple things to note here. The patindex of "some long string" will be the character index of the character at the beginning of that string. Also patindex gets awkward when you're looking for a specific patindex after another patindex since you basically have to search a substring of the original string for the second patindex. It might be easier to just take a given number of characters after the text? e.g. extract the following 10 characters? e.g. `SUBSTRING(NoteText, PATINDEX('%Demand Due Date:%', NoteText) + 16, 10)`

Comment: Is `Index of DemandDueDate date` less than `Index of DemandDueDate text` because there are dates that occur earlier in the source string than the phrase "Demand Due Date"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code will be easier for you to work with if you use a CTE and some stepwise refinement. That'll free you from trying to do everything with one hugely-nested SELECT statement.

```
;
WITH FirstCut as (
   SELECT 
      NotesSysID, 
      LocationOfText = PATINDEX('%Demand Due Date:%', NoteText),
      NoteText
   FROM #temp_ExtractedNotes
),
SecondCut as (
   SELECT
      NotesSysID,
      NoteText,
      -- making assumption date will be within first 250 chars of text
      DemandDueDateSection = SUBSTRING( NoteText, [LocationOfText], 250) 
   FROM  FirstCut
),
ThirdCut as (
    SELECT
      NotesSysID,
      NoteText,
      DemandDueDateSection,
      LocationOfDate = PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', DemandDueDateSection)
   FROM SecondCut
),
FourthCut as (
   SELECT 
     NotesSysID,
     NoteText,
     DateAsText = SUBSTRING( DemandDueDateSection, LocationOfDate, 10 )
   FROM ThirdCut
)
SELECT 
  NotesSysID,
  NoteText,
  DemandDueDate = CONVERT( DateTime, DateAsText)
FROM FourthCut
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having is because your second `PATINDEX` isn't finding the date you want; it's finding the first date in the string, which, as you noted, appears *before* the `PATINDEX` of the phrase you're searching for `%Demand Due Date:%`. The third parameter of `SUBSTRING` is `LENGTH`, which is to say how many characters *after* the second parameter you want to pull. By using that second `PATINDEX` value as the third parameter in your `SUBSTRING` you're returning a sub-string that starts where you want it to, and is of `LENGTH` equal to the number of characters into the string where that first date appears.

Which, of course, isn't what you want. To @ZLK's point in the comments, first, you need to do a nested `PATINDEX`. That's going to be pretty slow, so I'm hoping there aren't a bazillion records in your temp table.

Based on the sample image, it looks like the date you're interested in can appear a variable number of characters after `%Demand Due Date:%`. We'll start by adding 16 to the `PATINDEX` of `%Demand Due Date:%` (because that's how many characters are in `%Demand Due Date:%`, so we'll just start right after that). Then we'll pick up the next 100 characters. You can tweak that later if you need more or not that many.

So you're first `SUBSTRING` will look like this:

```
SUBSTRING(NoteText, PATINDEX('%Demand Due Date:%', NoteText) + 16, 100)
```

Now we have to search *that* sub-string for the second pattern, the one that *should* yield a date for you.

```
PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', SUBSTRING(NoteText, PATINDEX('%Demand Due Date:%', NoteText) + 16, 100))
```

The number returned there is the point where your date value starts within the 100 characters following `%Demand Due Date:%`. Armed with that number, you just need to `SUBSTRING` out the next ten characters, and, just for fun, `CAST` it as a `DATE`. That big ugly formula will look like this:

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(200) = 'foo bar Demand Due Date:    12/21/2018 bar foo foo bar';

SELECT 
    CAST(
        SUBSTRING(
            SUBSTRING
              (@test, PATINDEX('%Demand Due Date:%', @test) + 16, 100),
                 PATINDEX
                    ( '%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',
                     SUBSTRING
                      (@test, PATINDEX('%Demand Due Date:%', @test) + 16, 100)
                    )
            ,10)
         AS DATE);
```

Result:

```
2018-12-21
```

Rextester: https://rextester.com/KCY79989

Answer (score 0):

Grab a copy of [PatternSplitCM](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/String+Manipulation/94365/).

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.PatternSplitCM
(
       @List                VARCHAR(8000) = NULL
       ,@Pattern            VARCHAR(50)
) RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 
RETURN
WITH numbers AS (
  SELECT TOP(ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@List), 0))
   n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
  FROM
  (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) d (n),
  (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) e (n),
  (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) f (n),
  (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) g (n))
SELECT
  ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MIN(n)),
  Item = SUBSTRING(@List,MIN(n),1+MAX(n)-MIN(n)),
  Matched
 FROM (
  SELECT n, y.Matched, Grouper = n - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY y.Matched,n)
  FROM numbers
  CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT Matched = CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@List,n,1) LIKE @Pattern THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) y
 ) d
 GROUP BY Matched, Grouper;
```

Then it's pretty easy:

```
-- Sample Data
DECLARE @temp_ExtractedNotes TABLE (someID INT IDENTITY, NoteText VARCHAR(8000));
INSERT @temp_ExtractedNotes (NoteText) VALUES
('blah blah blah 2/4/2016... Demand Due Date: 1/05/2011; blah blah 12/1/2017...'),
('Yada yad..... Demand Due Date: 11/21/2016;...'),
('adas dasd asd a sd asdas Demand Due Date:         09/09/2019... 5/05/2005, 10/10/2010....'),
('nothing to see here - moving on... 01/02/2003!');

-- Solution
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES t.someID, ns.s, DueDate = CASE SIGN(nt.s) WHEN 1 THEN f.item END
FROM   @temp_ExtractedNotes AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('Demand Due Date:',t.NoteText))) AS nt(s)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(t.noteText, nt.s+16, 8000)))     AS ns(s)
CROSS APPLY dbo.patternsplitCM(ns.s,'[0-9/]')                  AS f
WHERE f.matched = 1
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.someID ORDER BY f.itemNumber);
```

**Results:**

```
someID      s                                        DueDate
----------- ---------------------------------------- ------------
1           1/05/2011; blah blah 12/1/2017...        1/05/2011
2           11/21/2016;...                           11/21/2016
3           09/09/2019... 5/05/2005, 10/10/2010....  09/09/2019
4           here - moving on... 01/02/2003!          NULL
```